# prevent navigation from nested component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I'm using angular 2 router, I have a component which is set to a be inserted in some route. I want to write another more general component, that I can place in that first component and will prompt the user when he trys to navigate away from the first component route and ask him if he is sure he wants to leave (with some logic which is irrelevant to this question)

I tried to use CanDeactivate in this Leave Dialog component but it is never being called (when switching routes).

Heres the simplified code:
AppComponent which defines the route:

```
  @RouteConfig([{
        component: FirstRouteComponent,
        name: "First",
        path: "/First",
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        component: SecondRouteComponentComponent,
        name: "Second",
        path: "/Second"
    }])
    export class AppComponent {
    }
```

The FirstRouteComponent template:

```
<leave-dialog></leave-dialog>
```

The leave dialog code:

```
export class LeaveDialogComponent implements CanDeactivate {

            constructor() {

            }
            public routerCanDeactivate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction): boolean|Promise<boolean> {
               // THIS FUNCITON IS NEVER CALLED EVEN WHEN I SWITCH ROUTE
            }
        }
```

If I put the CanDeactivate in the FirstRouteComponent code it does work. I'm not sure if its a bug or it is intended to work like that (or maybe im just doing something wrong). Is this the right approach or I should approach this task in a different way?

-------------------------------- EDIT -----------------------------------------

This was asked about a very old version of the router, this should already be implemented in the new router, more information:

[The issue I made in angular github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8722#event-811987661)

Comment: This was planned to be improved in the new router. I don't know if this is already implemented though (rc.1).

Comment: Are there any alternatives?